# Android Studio debug is very slow when inspectint the variable (Using Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So I have some large files that have 2000~3000 lines of code.
When debugging with emulator I set breakpoints and want to inspect some variables, it takes 1 minute to finish "Collecting data". Same with moving cursor to a variable doing "evaluating".
I don't know if this has something to do with Kotlin. It didn't seem to have this problem in Java even it is large file.

My PC is strong so should not cause this problem. Also upgrade Android Studio and Kotlin to the latest version.

Does anyone have large file that also have the same problem? It becomes very difficult to debug...very painful...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have similar problem when using kotlin, i don't have 2k-3k lines file and also it not take minutes to evaluate but for files with 200-400 lines it can take 5 sec, with java never happens. Seems like this have something with kotlin.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Thanks for the comment. So we can confirm kotlin does causes the problem...